# Creating conditional (or dyamic?) table in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra, flextable

I have an excel sheet with 40 rows and 40 ish columns. Each row is a name of a health plan to which I will be sending the results of an analysis.

.csv structure is:

```
id <- c("3235453", "321354365", "21354315", "32135135", "2121421", "123123123", "123123123", "123123123", "12312234", "234234234", "234234234", "3453453", "345345345", "2154651", "345345345", "34534534", "345345345", "345345345", "77878978", "234234234234")
Plan_name<- c("angers", "strasbourg",  Benzema, "angers", "montpellier", Arsenal,  "rouen", "limoges", CHG, "brest", "stanne", "aphp_psl", "stanne",      "strasbourg",  "clairval", "stanne", "stanne", "caen", Ventura, "brest")
Section.C<- c("X", "", "", "", "X", "X", "", "", "X", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "X")
Section.B<-c("", "X", "", "X", "", "", "X", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "X", "X")
Section.D<-c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "X", "", "X", "", "", "X", "", "", "", "", "X", "X")
df1 <- data.frame (id, Plan_name, Section.B, Section.C, Section.D)
```

I have done the first bit that will extract the results but I do not know how to create a table from it because the table depends on the excel sheet. What I have done so far is:

```
---
# in YAML
params:
  plan: "Ventura"
---

df = read.xlsx("MailMerge_2020.xlsx", sheet = 1)
t2 = df %>% filter(Plan-name == params$plan) %>% 
select(Section.B, Section.C, Section.D) %>% 
select_if(~ !any(is.na(.)))
```

How can I turn this into a table like the one below:

[image]

To clarify, not all plans will have findings for all sections so if plan X has only findings for sections B C D, those rows should show up.

Comment: Can you try to make a reproducible [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: might want to look into R shiny, Datatables, or something like Flexdashboard, with a few different tables

Comment: @Julian I added the .csv table that I am working on.

Comment: @Daniel_j_iii, I am trying to automate some word document reports, will I be able to use shiny for that?

Comment: Shiny or parametrized Rmarkdown https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html